# lombok for app engine on android studio

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, lombok

Is there a way to get Lombok to work for my app-engine module on android studio? It works fine with the app module, but for the app engine module it break gradle

```
provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6"
```